Extending ample line bundles on a log Calabi-Yau surface

Let $X$ be a smooth projective rational surface and suppose we have a nodal singular curve
$$
D \in |-K_X|
$$
( i.e., $U:=X\setminus D$ is a log Calabi-Yau surface with maximal boundary ).
Is there any condition on $(X,D)$ that implies there exists a line bundle $\mathcal M$ on $X$ such that $\mathcal M|_U$ is ample ( on $U$ ) and $$
\mathcal M|_D \cong \mathcal O_D
$$
For example, this is true if $U$ is quasi-affine ( e.g. $X$ is toric and $D$ is the torus boundary so that $U = X\setminus D$ is a torus ), but I do not think I have any good idea to deal with more general quasi-projective varieties.

Thank you in advance.
